# Swagger 3 / OpenApi How to add two descriptions to the same status code

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am trying to do some documentation to my small api.
What should I do in situation when on status code 400 I can have 2 possible descriptions?
I would like to do something like:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "description",
                content = {@Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                        schema = @Schema(implementation = StudentFullDTO.class))}),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "description" +
                "ExceptionResponseObject", content = @Content),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Odescription",
                content = @Content)})
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<StudentFullDTO> patch(@PathVariable String id,
                                            @RequestBody @Valid Map<Object, Object> fields) {
    StudentEntity studentEntity = studentEntityService.patchStudentEntity(id, fields);
    StudentFullDTO studentFullDTO = modelMapperService.mapObjectToObjectOfEnteredClass(studentEntity, StudentFullDTO.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(studentFullDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is it possible to define the same status multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to merge the two descriptions and specify them within the same `@ApiResponse(description = "...")` annotation. This is because OpenAPI Specification only allows defining each HTTP status code once per operation.

```java
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400",
    description = "Possible reasons: reason 1; reason 2",
    content = @Content),
```